# How to access value of text box contained in juice tag control

Tags: juice-ui

I am building asp.net web form. in some of my pages i added juice tag control to organized  collection data for Related use-cases.
For some reason unknown to me, when i switch my code from source view  to design view, i can't see all the Text boxes. But when i view it in the browser i see the text box and the button. Because of this i cannot access value of my  text box from code behind. Can some one tell me the cause of this and how i can get the values of my  text box from code behind.

```
 <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
 <div>
    <juice:tabs id="_Default" runat="server">
 <Juice:TabPage Title="Personaldata" ID="_Tab1">
<TabContent>
 <label>FirstName</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtfirstname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</TabContent>
 </Juice:TabPage>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

I try accessing my text box value as follows:

```
string firstname = txtfirstname.Text.Tostring();
```

But the text value is not recognized from code behind.